# isnt there a simple if condition to compre two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

so there are these two arrays:

```
$one = array("engineering", "applied", "mathematics");
$se = "Applied mathematics is a branch of mathematics that concerns itself with mathematical methods that are typically used in science, engineering, business, and industry.";
$two = explode(' ', $se);

if (//those 3 values from $one exist in $two) {
echo "i got it!";
} else {
echo "you dint get :(";
}
```

I was researching whit this but i did not find any simple answer. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to check if the values in one exist in two, if you get the same array back as a result you know they are in both.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`array_intersect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
if ( array_intersect( $one, $two ) ) {
    // arrays share one or more terms
}
```

You should probably `strtolower($se)`, since the intersect test is `===`.